# How do I structure my tests with the Python 'unittest' module?

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium

I'm trying to build a test framework for automated web testing in Selenium and [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html), and I want to structure my tests into distinct scripts.

So I've organised it as following:

File **base.py** - this will contain, for now, the base Selenium test case class for setting up a session.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

# Base Selenium Test class from which all test cases inherit.
class BaseSeleniumTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.close()
```

File **main.py** - I want this to be the overall test suite from which all the individual tests are run.

```
import unittest
import test_example

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SeTestSuite = test_example.TitleSpelling()
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(SeTestSuite)
```

File **test_example.py** - an example test case. It might be nice to make these run on their own too.

```
from base import BaseSeleniumTest

# Test the spelling of the title
class TitleSpelling(BaseSeleniumTest):
    def test_a(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)

    def test_b(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

The problem is that when I run *main.py*, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Python\testframework\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    SeTestSuite = test_example.TitleSpelling()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 191, in __init__
    (self.__class__, methodName))
ValueError: no such test method in <class 'test_example.TitleSpelling'>: runTest
```

I suspect this is due to the very special way in which `unittest` runs and I must have missed a trick on how the docs expect me to structure my tests. Any pointers?

Comment: +1 I was curious myself about why it wasn't working since it looked _mostly_ right. Based on your 'accept', I guess my suggestion worked?

Comment: @aneroid Yeah, sorry - the line `SeTestSuite = test_example.TitleSpelling()` was wrong, I misinterpreted the docs.

The best thing to do is put all your tests in a seperate folder and use the discover() method you suggested below, it will recurse through that dir and run all the tests in it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but in `main.py`, you might need a:

```
SeTestSuite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover(start_dir='.')
```

And the runner line should be (maybe):

```
# If your line didn't work
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(unittest.TestSuite(SeTestSuite))
```

Comment: @persepolis - did you require both lines I suggested or just the first?